# How can I stop an in-the-wall air conditioner from leaking air into the home?

Tags: insulation, walls, air-conditioning, hole

As far as I can tell, the air conditioner fits nearly perfectly in the hole, but there is considerable air leaking into the home through the bottom. I think it may be because of metal strips that line the bottom for some reason, causing the air conditioner to sit on the strips rather than on the floor of the hole, thus allowing air to flow in.

During installation of the air conditioner, I tried to fill the space around the air conditioner with foam insulation tape that I bought at the local hardware store, but that didn't work.

What's the best way to fully insulate an in-the-wall air conditioner? and how much would it cost for an independent contractor to do it? I'm reluctant to call the condo's maintenance crew because they are pretty incompetent.

Comment: By the bottom, do you mean that air comes between the window and the unit, or it is leaking through the actual unit?

Comment: Between the window and the unit.